# How to display Woocommerce FULL category description

Tags: woocommerce

For some reason the product category description that I wrote is being cut when being displayed in WooCommerce product category archive page, as you can see [here](https://ateneatours.com/tours-en-atenas/) *(the original is longer, here it is showing just a certain limit of characters and the adding 3 dots)*.

I would like to display the full description, and I have been struggling quite a lot already... I use the code snippets plugin to insert PHP. Other than that, I just have a basic knowledge of frontend, and I am friends with ChatGPT.

I would really appreciate any help.

I just know that it is not a matter of CSS, if we inspect the HTML element the text has already being cut. I tried other PHP snippets suggested by ChatGPT, but I had no success.

Comment: Note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) questions and answers are banned from Stack Overflow, please look carefully at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This seems to be related to your theme, as by default, WooCommerce displays the product category description without shortening it. so you should search and ask in your theme support pages.